# clear intervals and timeouts on nuxt.js build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

On my website I have a few intervals and timeouts set, for things such as a carousel. Now I do clear them on the components `destroyed()` lifecycle hook. But I am still getting this build warning.

[image]

This is an example of one of my components

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      carouselInterval: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.startInterval();
  },
  methods: {
    startInterval() {
      this.carouselInterval = setInterval(() => {
         ...
      }, 5000);
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(this.carouselInterval);
  }
</script>
```

I also have a timeOut like so

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      testTimeout: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.startTimeout();
  },
  methods: {
    startTimeout() {
      this.testTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
         ...
      }, 5000);
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearTimeout(this.testTimeout);
  }
</script>
```

Now I would assume this would clear these timing functions but, I am still getting this warning.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there another way to clear all timing functions on build?

**EDIT**

I am 100% sure I have cleaned up all timing functions on the `destroyed()` lifecycle hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `destroyed()` lifecycle hook does not get called whilst using SSR. You can read more about this here [SSR component lifecycle hooks](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#component-lifecycle-hooks)

This means you can not use it to clear timeouts on the server.

You can solve this issue by moving your interval functions to either be called in the `mounted()` or `beforeMount()` lifecycle hooks since they are only called on the client side.

In your example you can change your code to be

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      carouselInterval: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.startInterval();
  },
  methods: {
    startInterval() {
      this.carouselInterval = setInterval(() => {
         ...
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

This will prevent the `nuxt.js` build from timing out.